# Vue JS Sort Date with components using Computed Property

Tags: vue.js

I tried to sort the date using computed properties but it didnt work, if i using at methods and remove the slice, then it will sort as expected. I've tried to split the date also but still not working. I am not sure what caused the problem.

Kindly find my code as below.

App

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ingredients-list  v-for="(ingredient,index) in ingredients"
            :key="index"
            :index='index'
            :foodName="ingredient.food"
            :foodExpiry="ingredient.expiryDate">
        </ingredients-list>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                ingredients:[
                {
                    food:'carrot',
                    expiryDate:'2020-12-12'
                },
                {
                    food:'papaya',
                    expiryDate:'2018-1-15'
                },
                {
                    food:'orange',
                    expiryDate:'2021-10-13'
                },
                {
                    food:'meat',
                    expiryDate:'2019-4-23'
                }]
            }
        },
        computed: {
            sortedItems() {
                return this.ingredients.slice().sort( ( a, b) => {
                    return new Date(a.expiryDate)- new Date(b.expiryDate);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

components

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>{{index}}</h2>
        <h2>Food:{{foodName}}</h2>
        <h2>Expiry:{{foodExpiry}}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    export default {
        props:['foodName','foodExpiry'],
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are not using the `sortedItems` property.

Comment: Hi Abdelillah, i want it to be autosorted whenever the page update

Comment: You mean every time a component created and mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Anatoly said

> Computed props are never calculated if they are not used at all.

What you should be doing to solve the problem is :

1. Using `slice` method instead of `splice` since it mutates the original array:

```js
sortedItems() {
      return this.ingredients.slice()
             .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.expiryDate)- new Date(b.expiryDate));
}
```

2. Loop through the computed property and not the original array:

```html
<ingredients-list  v-for="(ingredient,index) in sortedItems"
            :key="index"
            :index='index'
            :foodName="ingredient.food"
            :foodExpiry="ingredient.expiryDate">
</ingredients-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you confused `splice` with `slice`. You need `slice` to get a copy of an array and to sort this copy:

```js
 sortedItems() {
            return this.ingredients.slice().sort( ( a, b) => {
                
                return new Date(a.expiryDate)- new Date(b.expiryDate);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried with slice but still unable to sort

Comment: Computed props are never calculated if they are not used at all.